# Create a new element once a user scrolled to the end of the list FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I have a `listview` with some TextFields inside, I think that it will be cool to add the textfield once a user scrolls down,
For example:

We have 5 Elements in ListView after a user reaches the fifth element and continued scrolling down a new element is created.
I couldn't find a solution for this task, I tried to check scrollposition for elements but unfortunately, I got an error

> flutter: Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter
>   'position' was called on null.

Here is the code..

```
ScrollController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = ScrollController();
  }

FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print(_controller.position.minScrollExtent);
                    },
                    child: Text('ds'),
                  ),

ListView
 - controller: _controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one solution if you want to add the new element on the end of the list view

```
ScrollController _controller;

ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: _items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text("Index : $index"));
              },
            )


@override
  void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }


_scrollListener() {
    if (_controller.offset >= _controller.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        message = "reach the bottom";
      });
    }
    if (_controller.offset <= _controller.position.minScrollExtent &&
        !_controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        message = "reach the top";
      });
    }
  }
```

in the `maxScrollExtent` you need to add the element into the listview. I hope it will helps you.

For more information visit [here](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac)

Comment: nice, it works, but how can I do this - when it reached the bottom you need to scroll a little bit further like 50 px further, so i can create a new textfield there

Comment: Sunny,
Thank you for the truth you let me see.
Sunny,
Thank you for the facts from A to Z.
from Bobby Hebb

Answer (score -1):

For creating a `ListView` with a dynamic number of children, you might want to check out the `ListView.builder` factory constructor.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, i) => Text('$i'),
)
```

Check out the ["Working with long lists"](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists) tutorial for more information.