# How to get ScrollListener to work with FutureBuilder?

Tags: list, flutter, scrollview

Was Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218907/create-a-new-element-once-a-user-scrolled-to-the-end-of-the-list-flutter) to detect when end of list reached but seems like the ScrollListener isn't working cause the print function I put to debug also doesn't give output

The List extends successfully using the button but my plan is to get rid of the button and add automatically when bottom is reached

```
class _AllProjectsState extends State<AllProjects> {

  ScrollController sc;

  void initstate() {
    sc = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
    sc.addListener(scListener);
  }

  scListener() {
    print("Changed");
    if( sc.offset >= sc.position.maxScrollExtent && !sc.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("Reached");
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Project Info'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body:FutureBuilder<Data>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if(snapshot.hasData)
            return ListView.builder(
              controller: sc,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.projects.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('${snapshot.data.projects[index].attributes.name}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),
                );
              }
            );
          else
            return Text('NotFound');
        }
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if(!full) {
            setState(() {
              page+=1;
            }); 
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You have typo `void initstate()` and need `@override`

code snippet

```
@override
  void initState() {
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Attributes {
  String name;

  Attributes({this.name});
}

class Project {
  Attributes attributes;

  Project({this.attributes});
}

class Data {
  List<Project> projects;

  Data({this.projects});
}

class AllProjects extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AllProjectsState createState() => _AllProjectsState();
}

class _AllProjectsState extends State<AllProjects> {
  ScrollController sc;
  Project project = Project(attributes: Attributes(name: "test"));
  List<Project> projectList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    projectList.add(project);
    sc = ScrollController();
    super.initState();
    sc.addListener(scListener);
  }

  scListener() {
    print("Changed");
    if (sc.offset >= sc.position.maxScrollExtent && !sc.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("Reached");
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Data> getData() {
    Project project = Project(attributes: Attributes(name: "123"));
    projectList.add(project);
    Data data = Data(projects: projectList);
    return Future.value(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Project Info'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: FutureBuilder<Data>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData)
              return ListView.builder(
                  controller: sc,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.projects.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        '${snapshot.data.projects[index].attributes.name}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            else
              return Text('NotFound');
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          /*if (!full) {
            setState(() {
              page += 1;
            });
          }*/
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: AllProjects(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```